# Does Django-1.5.1 still support the mod_python-3.3.1?

Tags: python, django, mod-python

My version of `Django` is 1.5.1, and the version of `mod_python` is 3.3.1.

Does `django` still support `mod_python`?

Comment: No. It has been removed since 1.5. Says in the docs, loud and clear: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/modpython/

Comment: thank you, I must choose anthor way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/modpython/) for version 1.4:

> Support for mod_python has been deprecated, and will be removed in
>   Django 1.5. If you are configuring a new deployment, you are strongly
>   encouraged to consider using mod_wsgi or any of the other supported
>   servers.

For version 1.5, the option is removed and instead you get this warning at the [deployment documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/):

> Chapter 12 of the Django Book (second edition) discusses deployment
>   and especially scaling in more detail. However, note that this edition
>   was written against Django version 1.1 and has not been updated since
>   mod_python was first deprecated, then completely removed in Django
>   1.5.

You are encouraged to use `mod_wsgi` instead. The documentation provides [comprehensive guidance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/) on how to deploy with wsgi.